# I have a question related to add a point to a GPS point

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I had a question that I have a GPS point (lat long) and I'd like to add noise that gaussian distribution with radius 10m. How should I write a python code?

Comment: What's the type of your GPS point? How would it look like? What exact output do you wish? What have you tried? Clarify the details more so that people here can help you.

Comment: @dibery On the surface, the question seems easy enough that a WHYT comment makes sense, but handling it correctly for points near the poles is not that easy.

Comment: (for OP) you could add some example input/output, and surely you've looked up the `random` module? Are you using some module to store the coordinates?

Comment: Idea: convert them to xyz coordinate, get a random point in the sphere, convert back.

Answer (score 0):

Generate random bearing and gaussian distribution of distance. Then calculate **Destination point given distance and bearing from start point** as [described here](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

```
def gauss_spread(lat, lon, radius):
    angle = random.random()*2.0*math.pi
    arcdist = random.gauss(0, radius) / 6371000
    rlat = math.radians(lat)
    newlat = math.asin(math.sin(rlat)*math.cos(arcdist) + math.cos(rlat)*math.sin(arcdist)*math.cos(angle))
    newlon = lon + math.degrees(math.atan2(math.sin(angle)*math.sin(arcdist)*math.cos(rlat),math.cos(arcdist)-math.sin(rlat)*math.sin(newlat)))
    return math.degrees(newlat), newlon
```

For small radii you can try the next approach. Generate random angle direction and gaussian distribution of distance (in degrees of earth arc). Then make correction by latitude factor.

```
import random, math

def gauss_spread_approx(lat, lon, radius):
    angle = random.random()*2.0*math.pi
    arcdist = random.gauss(0, radius * 180.0 / 20000000.0)
    return lat + arcdist * math.sin(angle),    \
           lon + arcdist * math.cos(angle) / math.cos(math.radians(lat))

print(gauss_spread_approx(45, 0, 111111))
```